# Searching Matrix field

Tags: matrix

Can’t believe this is the first time I’ve had to do this, but I need to search a field inside a matrix and I can’t find any documentation on this. Craft 2 if that matters. I had hoped something like

> craft.entries.search('matrixField:field:value')

would work but doesn’t seem to. Anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (please correct me if I missed something) you can only search for the entire matrix by `matrixField:value` and not certain fields within your matrix since the table `searchindexes` only contains the id of the matrix field itself, not the id of the field inside the matrix.

However: you could create a `Query` from your `ElementCriteriaModel` in PHP via

```
$command = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);
```

Join your matrixblock table as well as your matrixblock content table

```
$command->join("your matrixTable", "matrixTable.ownerId = elements.id");
$command->join("your matrixContentTable", "matrixContentTable.elementId = matrixTable.id");
```

And search for your field with a `where`

```
$command->andWhere('MyAwesomeField LIKE %whatever%');
```